# how do make a image circle using next.js image component using next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make an image look like [image: example image] with the latest next.js 13 using next.js image component but it's going looks like an egg shape a little bit.

I try with this code:

```
<Image
   src='/profile.jpg'
   width={100}
   height={100}
   className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-[50%]"
   alt="profile-pic"`
 />
```

but the output is [image: looks like this] now what would be the solution ? If anybody faces already this issue please help me

Comment: This is not reflecting on my system. Can you just try to add TailwindCSS class `min-w-[100px]` . this may be help you.

Comment: I tried with `min-w-[100px]` but still the same issue

Comment: Can you provide the section code because I didn't get this issue using only Image component.

Comment: @VivekTarsariya
`
<Image
      src={ashrafulmijan}
      alt="ashrafulmijan"
      className="rounded-[50%] min-w-[100px] p-2 border"
  />
`

Comment: @VivekTarsariya please try your local first what are my expectation

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this image inside another div and apply `border-radius` to that div along with `overflow-hidden`. If you force the image to have specific width and height, it will be stretched, which is not good. Thus, Next.js Image component will maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

```
<div className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-[50%] inline-block" style={{width: '100px', height: '100px'}}>
  <Image
   src='/profile.jpg'
   width={100}
   height={100}   
   alt="profile-pic"`
 />
</div>
```

Comment: still the same problem with this code.

Comment: Please share codesandbox

Comment: thank you for your kind response. now the issue is solved by myself. the issue has come from tailwind CSS default img tag style: height auto by default. and now the solution is `h-[100px]` instead of next.js Image component height prop